# TwitterOAuth: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'TwitterOAuthException'

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, xampp

I'm working with Abraham's `twitteroauth` to implement Twitter OAuth in my application. While running my application, this is the error I'm encountering:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message '<!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us"> <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <title>Twitter / ?</title> <link href="https://abs.twimg.com/favicons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://abs.twimg.com/errors/fullscreen_errors-91ecc652e4fafac52ce8a1a8a181ad24.css"> </head> <body> <div class="topbar js-topbar"> <div class="global-nav" data-section-term="top_nav"> <div class="global-nav-inner"> <div class="container"> <ul class="nav js-global-actions"> <li class="home"> <a class="nav-logo-link" href="https://twitter.com"><img class=" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/twitta/redirect.php on line 158
```

redirect.php (till line 158th):

```
<?php
namespace Abraham\TwitterOAuth;
session_start();
//require('twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php');


/*
include 'twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
*/





/**
 * The most popular PHP library for use with the Twitter OAuth REST API.
 *
 * @license MIT
 */


use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Util\JsonDecoder;
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
//use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth as Config;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response as Response;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\HmacSha1 as HmacSha1;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Consumer as Consumer;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Request as Request;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Util as Util;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException as TwitterOAuthException;
/**
 * TwitterOAuth class for interacting with the Twitter API.
 *
 * @author Abraham Williams <abraham@abrah.am>
 */
class TwitterOAuth extends Config
{
    const API_VERSION = '1.1';
    const API_HOST = 'https://api.twitter.com';
    const UPLOAD_HOST = 'https://upload.twitter.com';

    /** @var Response details about the result of the last request */
    private $response;
    /** @var string|null Application bearer token */
    private $bearer;
    /** @var Consumer Twitter application details */
    private $consumer;
    /** @var Token|null User access token details */
    private $token;
    /** @var HmacSha1 OAuth 1 signature type used by Twitter */
    private $signatureMethod;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string      $consumerKey      The Application Consumer Key
     * @param string      $consumerSecret   The Application Consumer Secret
     * @param string|null $oauthToken       The Client Token (optional)
     * @param string|null $oauthTokenSecret The Client Token Secret (optional)
     */
    public function __construct($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthToken = null, $oauthTokenSecret = null)
    {
        $this->resetLastResponse();
        $this->signatureMethod = new HmacSha1();
        $this->consumer = new Consumer($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
        if (!empty($oauthToken) && !empty($oauthTokenSecret)) {
            $this->token = new Token($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);
        }
        if (empty($oauthToken) && !empty($oauthTokenSecret)) {
            $this->bearer = $oauthTokenSecret;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $oauthToken
     * @param string $oauthTokenSecret
     */
    public function setOauthToken($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret)
    {
        $this->token = new Token($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getLastApiPath()
    {
        return $this->response->getApiPath();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLastHttpCode()
    {
        return $this->response->getHttpCode();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLastXHeaders()
    {
        return $this->response->getXHeaders();
    }

    /**
     * @return array|object|null
     */
    public function getLastBody()
    {
        return $this->response->getBody();
    }

    /**
     * Resets the last response cache.
     */
    public function resetLastResponse()
    {
        $this->response = new Response();
    }

    /**
     * Make URLs for user browser navigation.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param array  $parameters
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function url($path, array $parameters)
    {
        $this->resetLastResponse();
        $this->response->setApiPath($path);
        $query = http_build_query($parameters);
        return sprintf('%s/%s?%s', self::API_HOST, $path, $query);
    }

    /**
     * Make /oauth/* requests to the API.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param array  $parameters
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws TwitterOAuthException
     */
    public function oauth($path, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $response = array();
        $this->resetLastResponse();
        $this->response->setApiPath($path);
        $url = sprintf('%s/%s', self::API_HOST, $path);
        $result = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'POST', $parameters);

        if ($this->getLastHttpCode() != 200) {
            throw new TwitterOAuthException($result);
        }
```

What seems to be raising the `TwitterOAuthException` in the above code? I have been trying to find a solution for this bug for hours now but haven't really found anything which could be of any help.

Comment: I did answer before to this question, and you accepted the answer - but my answer is not here?

Comment: @AngelM. That didn't fix my problem. I did accept that answer, and it did solve one aspect of the problem, but I still couldn't figure out why the exception was being generated. And this is a whole new Exception that is being generated by the code.

Comment: Look at the exception message. I looks like you are getting a 404 error from Twitter.